# Fullcalendar + event drop + ajax + bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I’m using fullcalendar and I have a problem with this code:

```
eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'index.php?option=com_component&view=verify&layout=verify', 
                data: 'id=5', 
                dataType: 'json', 
                success: function(data) 

                    {
                        if((data[0])==0) {
                            $.smallBox({
                                title : "<b>OK!!</b>",
                                content : “The event has moved correctly!",
                                color : "#739E73",
                                timeout: 3600,
                                icon : "fa fa-check shake animated"
                            });

                        } else {
                            $('#remoteModal').modal({
                                backdrop: false,
                                keyboard: false
                            });
                            $('#remoteModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
                                    revertFunc();
                                    console.log(ev_drag);
                                    ajaxcall.abort();
                            });

                        }
                    }
             });
             },
```

So when I drop an event and the result from the ajax request is not 0 it launch a modal window asking some settings to the user. When the user close the modal the revertFunc() is launched; this function will work correctly only the first time: if there is a second or a third (an so on..) drop of events and the revertFunc() is launched all of the dropped events will be moved on the calendar..

Could you help me?

Comment: One problem is that you could be binding the 'hide.bs.modal' event to $('#remoteModal') more than once. So, upon every `n`th time eventDrop is called and the ajax succeeds and everything, that function will be executed `n` times.

Comment: the function has to be executed everytime the event ‘hide.bs.modal’ is launched..the problem is that every revertFunc() should be related to a single event, instead it seems that reverFunc moves inappropriately also the previously events..

Comment: That seems consistent with what I've suggested. You could try adding to the top of that function, `$('#remoteModal').off('hide.bs.modal');` That unbinds the event from the modal right after it happens so the event handlers don't "pile up."